# Item separators when stringing phone numbers together for B-cards

Tags: adobe-indesign, lists

I have an CSV file with info for about 82 different Business cards. The CSV file has 5 possible different phone numbers for each card with separate columns for each phone number. (Ex. Office, Mobile, Home Fax, BP Fax, KB Office, KB Fax)

The problem is some cards will have only 1 phone number, but they can have up to 4 numbers per card. Keep in mind the phone number are all listed on the same line.

The business card style has this " | ", as the separator for the phone numbers. How do I get the " | " to NOT show up in the front of the first phone number if the first phone number is NOT within the first column in the CSV file? (If first phone number column in CSV is blank?)

Here is what my text box looks like in InDesign: (all on one line)

«empty»Office: «OfficePhone» | Mobile: «CellPhone» | Home Fax: «fax» | BP Fax:  «BPFaxNumber» | KB Office: «KBPhoneNo» | KB Fax: «KBFaxNo»

Comment: This is for creating business cards within InDesign.

Comment: Is your problem essentially the same as in [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/946/52050)?